# Search all levels of user hierarchy returning related members from every level

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

We have a `hierarchy` [Company] withing the `Dimension` [Client] - this hierarchy is multi-level with three defined levels HoldingCompany, Name and OwnerName.

Is this the most efficient way of searching for a name withing these levels or should I be explicitly naming the levels and somehow using the `OR` operator?

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelName] AS
        [Client].[Company].Level.Name
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelNumber] AS
        [Client].[Company].Level.Ordinal
SELECT
    {
    FILTER(
        [Client].[Company].AllMembers,
            (
            InStr(1, [Client].[Company].currentmember.name, "Smith") <> 0
            ) 
        )
    } ON 1,
    {
    [Measures].[LevelName],
    [Measures].[LevelNumber] 
    } ON 0
FROM [ourCube]
```

Comment: You might also look into the [descendants](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146075.aspx) function.

Comment: @mmarie - `descendants` function against the `All` level, instead of using `.AllMembers` ? Which is quicker ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use descendants against ALLMEMBERS.  All is an actual level in the hierarchy. Allmembers is a function that returns all of the members that are a child of All in the hierarchy. If using allmembers works, I would guess that it would try to cause it to evaluate it against the set of all members rather than the single All member, which seems like it would take longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The way you coded is perfect as long as you want to apply the filter on all the members across all the level.

If you want to search only on the Owner Name then specifying the level name matters.